# Kernel upgrade 3.5.0-39-generic prevents virtual box from running

Tags: upgrade, kernel, virtualbox

I just performed the kernel upgrade as part of the regular system upgrade. As usually on previous kernel upgrades, I had to install the kernel headers and recompile VirtualBox drivers. This process worked normally and VirtualBox is able to launch, but it stalls trying to run the virtual machine. When I backup to 3.5.0-37 (using GRUB menu, and recompile VirtualBox drivers) it returns to working state.

The version string from `uname -a` after upgrading is `3.5.0-39-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 13 18:33:05 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and my system is a Lenovo laptop W520 that has been running Ubuntu/VirtualBox for a couple of years already.

Is there anyone experiencing this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install **linux-headers** and **dkms** for your kernel version:

```
sudo aptitude install linux-headers-3.5.0-39-generic dkms
```

and do not forget to do that for include the driver in the kernel:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Also be sure that vboxusers group is activated in your username group.

I hope all this could help you. I have the same version of the kernel that yours, and VirtualBox runs flawlessly...